# How do I properly print out the contents of the created file?

Tags: java, file

I am creating a program to create a new file and put 100 random integers from 0 to a 100 in it. After inputting the numbers I need return the contents of the file in increasing order. However right now I can't seem to figure out what is causing nothing to be printed out.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    try {
        File f = new File("integerFile.txt");
        if (!f.exists()) {
            f.createNewFile();
        }
        int arr[] = new int[100];
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(f, true);
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            arr[i] = (int) ((Math.random() * 100));
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < arr.length - i - 1; j++) {
                int temp;
                if (arr[j] > arr[j + 1]) {
                    temp = arr[j];
                    arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
                    arr[j + 1] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            pw.print(arr[i] + " ");
        }
        pw.close();
    } catch (
    IOException ioe)
    {
        System.out.println("No file exits");
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Have you stepped through the code in the debugger, examined the variables, etc.?  That is the 1st thing to do.

Comment: I am not sure how to use the debugger. However, I went through my code line by line to see if the syntax makes sense. I still can't seem to figure out how to print the contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't printing because `pw.print()` is writing to the file "integerFile.txt". To print to the console you have to use `System.out.println(arr[i]);`

However, you will want to create a new loop to do this. Otherwise you won't be writing to your file.

If you want to read the file after you have written to it and then print out the contents of the file try this:

```
FileReader myFileReader;
myFileReader = new FileReader(//Your file name);
BufferedReader b; 
b = new BufferedReader(myFileReader);//Read the file
//Write a loop to print out the contents
String line;
line = b.readLine();
while (line != null)
{
    System.out.println(line);
    line = b.readLine();
}
b.close();
```

Comment: I am trying to print the contents of the file that is being written in. How would I print the contents i wrote in the file ?